# Attempting to customize spinner with adapter

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I want to do nothing more than change the font Typeface and size of my spinner text.

I have made some initial attempts.  Nothing is crashing, but my spinner is blank.  (I also have yet to implement the custom Typeface, I am just trying to get the spinner to work first.

In code:

```
protected SpinnerSortAdapter sAdapter;
    protected Spinner sort;
    protected String[] strings;

        sort = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        strings = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sorting_items);
        SpinnerSortAdapter sAdapter = new SpinnerSortAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, strings);
        sAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sort.setAdapter(sAdapter);
        sort.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

Adapter:

```
public class SpinnerSortAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
public SpinnerSortAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        String[] strings) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, strings);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    if (view instanceof TextView) {
        ((TextView) view).setTextSize(5);
    }
    return view;
}

public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    return (row);
}
```

}`enter code here`

Comment: Why don't you use the [SpinnerAdapter][1]?


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html

Comment: What does *my spinner is blank* means? If you want to change the text in the spinner's dialog you have to implement `getDropdownView`.

Comment: Mostly because most of the tutorials I saw used `ArrayAdapter`. I'll use whatever works of course!

Comment: @Luksprog It's blank, as in my string array doesn't populate it,.

Comment: You're using the wrong `ArrayAdapter` super class. You can't pass an array like that. Right now you're implementing the ArrayAdapter that takes two ints, a layout file and an id to a `TextView` from that layout(but you provide an id to an array?!?) so the adapter is empty.

Comment: I just updated my code.  Can you take a look?

Comment: It's basically the code from my answer. Use the method `getStringArray` instead of `getTextArray` then modify the view like you want in the two methods based on which text you want to change. You can even use Sam's answer to do what you want.

Comment: I will respond in your answer now, cause I see yours is more correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not initializing the adapter correctly. Your version of `ArrayAdapter` that takes two ints, one pointing to a layout file for the row and an int representing the id of a `TextView` widget from that layout file. This adapter will be empty. Your code should be like this:

```
String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sorting_items);
SpinnerSortAdapter adapter = new SpinnerSortAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
```

Also the adapter would be changed to:

```
 public class SpinnerSortAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public SpinnerSortAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, strings);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (view instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) view).setTextSize(5);
        }
        return view;
    }

    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        return (row);
    }
}
```

Comment: It keeps telling me to remove `items` to match (Context, int)

Comment: I've given you an upvote, because you reminded me to use `ArrayAadapter.createFromResource()` (as another way) to properly use `R.array.name` when creating an adapter.

Comment: @Luksprog The code makes so much more sense, but I am still getting a blank list in the spinner.  I will update my code again...

Comment: @KickingLettuce Implementing custom font size and typeface shouldn't be a problem(just work with the View you get in those methods). Also the instanceof check isn't necesarry if you use those layouts file because they are `TextViews`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually have already implemented Typeface before.  Just not with Spinners.  Never used anything but the default spinner actually.  Also thanks for the reminder on instanceof.  I'll remove that.

Answer (score 2):

A much easier and faster route is to customize the *layouts* that you pass to your adapter rather than the adapter itself:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item, R.array.sorting_items);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Save this as `spinner_dropdown_item.xml` in `res/layout`:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" 
    android:textSize="15sp"/>
```

(I just copied `simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml` and added the textSize attribute at the bottom. You should do the same with `simple_spinner_item` layout.)

This approach is faster because you are not changing any attributes at runtime. The XML is pre-processed. While the custom adapter changes the typeface and size everytime you call `getView()` or `getDropDownView()`...

Comment: Seems simple, but what about the custom Typeface?

Comment: Use the `fontFamily` attribute. If you look at [TextView's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) you can find a table that lists every XML attribute and its corresponding method.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I thought about using the same `createFromResources` method but you can't set a custom font in the xml on a normal `TextView`(I may be mistaken but `fontFamily` isn't for this).

Comment: @Luksprog Thanks for the heads up, I haven't used custom fonts before, I'm just relying on the documentation. [`setTypeface()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface%28android.graphics.Typeface%29) lists an attribute `typeface` (among others). Hopefully one of these should work for custom fonts.